# bibulous invalid syntax

Tags: biblatex, biber, bibulous

I have some special requirements for my bibliography layout and would like to realize this with bibulous. I have built a example document which can be compiled into a PDF with lualatex and biber without any problems. But when I try to exchange biber with bibulous I get an error message:

```
  File "C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Lib/site-packages/bibulous.py", line 1171
    except Exception, err:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the reason for this? To me it looks like it is a bug in the bibulous code itself. But I can't believe that, because then it would have been noticed by others, and should have been fixed long ago.

This is my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, bibstyle=authortitle, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{testrefs.bib}
\bibliography{teststyle.bst}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\author{Thats Me}
\date{\today}
\title{Bibliography Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Book}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{book1990}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{book1990}.

\section{Article}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{article2020}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{article2020}.

\section{Techreport}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{techreport1880}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{techreport1880}.

\section{Bibliography}
\printbibliography[heading=none]

\end{document}
```

and my bib file:

```
@techreport{techreport1880,
  title={MyTechreport},
  author={TechAuthor},
  institution={TechInstitution},
  year={1880},
}

@book{book1990,
  title={MyBook},
  author={BookAuthor},
  isbn={978-3-86680-192-9},
  series={BookSeries},
  year={1990},
  publisher={BookPublisher},
}

@article{article2020,
  title={MyArticle},
  author={ArticleAuthor},
  journal={ArticleJournal},
  year={2020},
  volume={1},
}
```

and my bst file (work in progress):

```
TEMPLATES:
book = <author>, \textit{<title>} - <year>.
techreport = \textbf{<institution>:<year>}, <title>
article = \textbf{<title>}, <author> - <journal> (<year>), Vol. <valume>, Nr. <number>, P. <pages>

SPECIAL-TEMPLATES:
authorlist = <author.to_namelist()>
authorname.n = [<authorlist.n.prefix> ]<authorlist.n.last>[ <authorlist.n.first.initial()>.][ <authorlist.n.middle.initial()>.][,  <authorlist.n.suffix>.]
au = <authorname.0>, ..., <authorname.9>
citelabel = [<author>:<year>]

OPTIONS:
nothing = {}
```

The compilation works fine with this command chain:

```
lualatex test -shell-escape
biber test
lualatex test -shell-escape
lualatex test -shell-escape
```

but if I replace biber with:

```
python C:/ProgramData/Miniconda3/Lib/site-packages/bibulous.py test.aux
```

the above error occurs.

Comment: as far as I can see bibulous assumes a document marked up as for bibtex, not biblatex, so remove `biblatex`  and `addbibresource` the argument of `\bibliography` should be your `bib` file (without the `.bib`) not the bst and reference the template via `\bibliographystyle`

Comment: This does not seem to change anything with the Error message.

Comment: I don't have bibulous but fixing the tex document and re-running latex is probably a necessary first step

Comment: I have changed the document structure to bibtex, compiling also works with bibtex, but the bibulous command leads to the same error message as mentioned above (invalid syntax).

Comment: You could fix the example in the question .sorry can't help more, as I don't have it insalled. you could report here  https://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/instructions_for_reporting_bugs.html#where-to-report-a-bug. oh it's from 2013? Does it need python2 rather than python 3 ?

Comment: (python3 if you have 2019 update https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/commit/4313f1b92f321672ebb2e528fbf24912b67b063c)

Comment: why do you want to use bibulous instead of biblatex/biber (which is used by much more people and where you can ask more easily for support)?

Comment: i would like to use bibulous because i want to use some special styles. As far as I have seen, it is much clearer and shorter to define such style conditions with bibulous, see e.g. here: http://nzhagen.github.io/bibulous/faq.html#what-is-the-difference-between-using-bibulous-and-using-biblatex-biber

That's 5 lines versus 64 if I haven't lost count.

Comment: well the page is from 2013 and the system doesn't seemed to have attracted many users, so  you should perhaps wonder why. Apart from this: biblatex has evolved quite a lot in this 8 years, at it knows now `eprinttype` which handles links like pubmed or arxiv.

Comment: Ok, assuming I would switch to biblatex and biber, is there a tutorial / documentation on how to set custom styles for depending on the document type? (Just so I can have a look, not too detailed as it's not the actual topic of this question).

Comment: Note for Bibulous the code on Github (https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/blob/master/bibulous.py) looks different around line 1171, and the line quoted in the error message does not appear in the file. Maybe Anaconda/Miniconda has an old version in their repository? In that case you could try to use the version from Github directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David Carlisle pointed out in the initial comment, the main problem you are encountering here is that the .tex file is formatted for Biblatex rather than Bibtex. Note that I am running on Python 3.9.2, and did not get the same errors that you report here, when running Bibulous on the files. I get different errors. However, if I change the document file to the following, then PDFLatex runs without error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\author{Thats Me}
\date{\today}
\title{Bibliography Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Book}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{book1990}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{book1990}.

\section{Article}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{article2020}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{article2020}.

\section{Techreport}
This section illustrates the citation of the book class. A normal citation with the par command gives this output \cite{techreport1880}. And a parenthesized citation with parencite gives this output \parencite{techreport1880}.

\section{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{teststyle}  % bst file
\bibliography{main}            % bib file

\end{document}
```

and I get the following formatted PDF:

[image: Formatted PDF from running PDFLatex and Bibulous on the provided file.]

Comment: Thanks to all for the help.
As i mentioned, after switching from biblatex to bibtex, I still get the same error message. By the hint that it works with python 3.9.2 I updated my python environment. This has changed the error message description, but still points to the same place (line 1171). Then I compared the github code with the one I have locally. And guess what, the code is different. Then I replaced the github file with my local one, and now it works. So it seems that I had an old version. Interestingly, I could not upgrade it via pip, as pip said that bibulous is already up to date.

Comment: Yeah, the pip version is quite out-of-date at the moment.